# Instagram API URL to return all images with a certain tag

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I'm using this URL to return a count for all images tagged with yolo:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/yolo?access_token=

Is there anyway to return the image URLs and their metadata as well? I can only seem to get hold of the image URLs from the user related to the access token.

I can retrive the data I need by scraping Instagram with the following call. How can I extract the .window._sharedData as a json object?

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/yolo/");
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        // .window._sharedData;
        console.log(result);
        // ('request successful ' + xhr.responseText.);

    }
    else {
        console.log('request failed: ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the media and the related metadata, you need to use the **`GET /tags/tag-name/media/recent`** function, like so: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/yolo/media/recent?access_token=`

First you'll get a list of 20 (if I remember correctly, can't check right now) most recent medias (images and/or videos) and then you have to check the id of the last media item you got. Then you just create a new request with `MIN_TAG_ID` set to that value.

Repeat until you have all the medias from that tag.

Basically all functions in the Instagram API that return a list of items, will have some sort of paging enabled. You just need to request the results page by page to get the full collection.

---

If you're testing your application on the sandbox, you'll get a different set of results than what the live application would get. Here's the explanation from Instagram's API documentation:

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of media: **`/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent`**. The response returned by this endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, **it will return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to the last 20 for each user**.

Comment: This only returns the user's images with that tag. The URL I'm using returns a count of all images on the site with that hashtag. Do you know how I can get all images with that tag by all users?

Comment: @TimmyTimmy Are you sure about that? The function is supposed to return all media by all users for that specific hashtag. You just need to go through all the pages and you'll see that the resulting list of media matches with the count returned by your original function.

Comment: This is the return I get: {"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []} The data array is empty?

Comment: First of all you should use the new parameter names `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` since your app might suddenly stop working if Instagram drops the support for `next_max_id` and `min_id` property names. Secondly, your problem is that you're most likely running in sandbox mode. Then you can only see posts by yourself and up to 9 additional sandbox users. I'll update my main answer to reflect this information.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. Thank you. I don't suppose you know of any hack to get this data do you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just know how the public API works.

Comment: I updated my question if you have a moment to take a look? Thank you.